# Running a .sh in a Desktop

Tags: bash, gnome, scripts

I have written a .sh file to run housekeeping (update etc). I have also written a .desktop in-order to run my .sh

The .desktop opens a terminal and runs the .sh in it.

It works in principle, but the terminal is closed before its all over. My code is

.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Update
Type=Application
Icon=/home/...
Exec=gnome-terminal -e /home/user/MyScripts/HouseKeeping.sh
```

.sh file:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt auto remove
sudo apt clean
```

When I run the .sh in a terminal, it all works fine.

Would the issue with gnome be that it needs a Y/N response when it runs .sh?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `Exec=gnome-terminal -e bash -c /home/user/MyScripts/HouseKeeping.sh`, `Exec=gnome-terminal -e sh -c /home/user/MyScripts/HouseKeeping.sh`
or some variation of that

Comment: what does the bash -c do?

Comment: Why would you need a `.desktop` file to do that ? I think `.sh` works fine.

Comment: The `sudo` commands in your `.sh` script run via the `.desktop` file has nowhere to ask for a password. Read `man sudoers`, about "`NOPASSWD`". Or, copy the `$DISPLAY` variable from your GUI session, to get `sudo` to ask your GUI display.

Comment: Ray Wu, Thanks for your help. It didn't make any difference. The Terminal shuts down after the execution

Comment: Hi Liso, I want to click on an icon from my desktop, that is the reason for the .desktop

Comment: Hi Waltinator, I have already taken care of that, thx

Answer (score 0):

**Edit your `.desktop` file** with this : 
Fix `Exec` and add `Terminal` values

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Update
Comment=Update & Upgrade
Icon=/usr/share/icons/path/to/your/icon.svg
Exec='/home/user/MyScripts/HouseKeeping.sh'
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Make the `.desktop` file executable

```
chmod +x /path/to/file.desktop
```

**Your script `.sh`** should start with the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
# try adding : sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt upgrade
# try with -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt auto remove
# try replacing it with : sudo apt-get -y autoremove
sudo apt clean
```

Comment: Thanks camp.fr. I did have a shebang, just forgot to type it here. I have also tried your Desktop, it still behaves as mine. The Terminal closes after its done

Comment: you mean `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'ls; exec bash'`, exec bash will keep it open

Comment: Why would I use a bash? I have already got a .sh file being executed from the Exec line. Also your solution does not work. No idea why though...

Comment: I have put a sleep 10 at the bottom of my .sh, will see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I just included a sleep 300 at the end of my .sh file. With regards to y/n questions, it all works fine.

Thank you all for the valuable suggestions